# Issue in getting context path inside jsp?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, request, el

My jsp lies at below location

```
http://myApp.com/myWebApp/customer/images/customer.jsp
```

My image(accessed thru customer.jsp) lies at

http://myApp.com/myWebApp/images/customer.gif

In image tag  i am making the absoulte path as below

```
src="${param.contextPath}images/customer.gif"
```

just for info i am using param here becoz this is how we access request params in EL.

I was expecting that ${param.contextPath} will return /myWebApp/ but it is returning /myWebApp/customer/. **Is there a way i can get
just context path(not with customer namespace) i.e /myWebApp/ from request?**

Comment: Just change it to `src="customer.gif"`. Or was there a reason for the context path?

Comment: Using relative paths from within JSP files can lead to trouble under some circumstances (for example, when the JSP file is included by another JSP file somewhere else in the directory hierarchy).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you read the context path from a request parameter, then someone must have populated it beforehand with some value. That value was incorrect, and as there is no information as to who populated this value and how, not much can be said about it.

Try using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead. That is the standard method to obtain the context path under which your application is deployed.

Answer (score 6):

Use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead