# Can't get Spring MVC Resource Handler to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**EDIT:** This is on spring 3.1.0

I've seen other questions on this subject, and tried a few things but nothing seems to work for me.

I plan to add my version number to the path of static resources, to force requests from browsers on new versions, so I started doing as instructed on [this part of the spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

Before any change, the path `<context>/assets/js/base/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js` works and points to an existing file.

What I did was add to my java config class the following:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/my-assets/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/assets/**");
}
```

The plan was to use the version number, instead of just `my-assets` once I get it to work. But it didn't, even though my logs said:

```
17:28:56,077  INFO [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/my-assets/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

I then tried some variations:

`.. ("/my-assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");`

`.. ("/my-assets/js/base/lib/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/js/base/lib/");`

`.. ("/my-assets/js/base/lib/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/js/base/lib/**");`

And even tried adding these afterwards:

`registry.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);`
`registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);`

To no avail. In all cases `<context>/assets/js/base/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js` **still** worked and `<context>/my-assets/js/base/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js` **didn't**.

This is my directory structure:

```
├── assets
│   ├── charts
│   ├── css
│   ├── font
│   ├── images
│   └── js
├── META-INF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── jsp
    ├── layout
    └── tags
```

Any thoughts on what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Spring 4.1 has a versioning resource manager FYI http://www.infoq.com/presentations/resource-spring-mvc-4-1

Comment: Thanks Neil! We're using 3.1 and can't upgrade right now, but I'll keep that in mind. It will surely make things easier.

Comment: Have you ruled out your DispatcherServlet not correctly registering the requests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources

Comment: That was it @seanhodges! I totally forgot my dispatcher had the URL pattern `/app/*`! Adding this to my requests made it work! Would you post an answer so I can mark it? Thanks!