# CSS resources are not able to access in spring 4 mvc

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried lot of example and references to get it working Still unable to access

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources)

but still no luck in accessing the resources

here goes my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.raghu")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

Appconfig is the pace where i have added the resource location i added it in dispatcher-servlet.xml also and tried

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

dispatcher-servelt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

  <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
  <annotation-driven />

  <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
  <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.raghu" />

</beans:beans>
```

**JSP**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/component.css" />
```

here i tried giving the context path also

Comment: Configurations looks ok,  think that only think that you have to do is to change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/component.css" />` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />` if the `/component.css` is located at the `src\main\resources` directory

Comment: i did that too... no luck!!

Comment: Also I've noticed a difference between your and my code in `AppConfig`. Change it to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Ok, so I'm putting comments as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configurations looks ok, think that only think that you have to do is to change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/component.css"/>` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />` if the `component.css` is located at the src\main\resources directory.

In additional you can change `AppConfig` to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: The links were fine it was just that i had to extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter