# How to ignore a particular URI pattern in spring RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My spring controller should take any get request of any URI type except a URI which started with `/resources/*` as this is the call, if I am not wrong, done by spring container to load all the static content in view page.

Current configuration is like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/*")
```

which working fine for request with URI `/` or `/example` but if someone make a typo in URI eg. `/example/random/char` it is throwing exception trace page not found(404) which is pretty obvious and leads me to make `value="/**"`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/**")
```

then the request with URI `/` or `/example` are unable to load my static content `.js, .css or .png` files in my view page. This lead me to the conclusion that spring internally make get call to load these files with an URL pattern eg. `http://localhost:8080/resources/my.jpg`.

**Note:-** I intentionally removed my project name by configuring tomcat.

**Update**
Okay @dimitrisli comment make me realize that I need to elaborate a little about my project.

It basically a URL redirecting component. A user simply call my application through get request and ended with redirecting to the actual page.

For example user request me throw their browser with URL let's say `http://localhost:8080/sample`. Now my application needs to split the URL to get the string `sample` and search in db for the actual URL against it(so `sample` is the alias name for a really long URL). If URL exist it will redirect to the actual page else page does not exist message will show.

Answer (score 1):

(Update based on comments)

This is how you can deal with 404 errors.

**Option 1**

in `web.xml` include the following to forward on main page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

or your custom error specific page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/my-custom-error-page</location>
</error-page>
```

**Option 2**

Define a catch-all error handler at the Controller layer:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
    log.error("There was an exception thrown! ", e);
    return "index";
}
```

---

Based on the name of the folder you want to exclude (resources) and your description (.js/.css/.png) I'm assuming you are referring to the static content of your web project.

You need to explicitly define the static content in your `dispatcher servlet xml` as follows (follow the directory convention of your project for static data):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/resources/fonts/" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that is not my concern. I have already done this. 
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

Comment: What is exactly your concern? If you have defined the resources details then all static content is served by the webapp and it's not going through the @RequestMapping

Comment: Yes you are right but it is not going through RequestMapping when value="/*" but it is going to RequestMapping when value="/**"

Comment: This is not how you deal with 404 errors. "/**" at @RequestMapping level is not a viable solution since you are shortcircuiting all requests through this single mapping. I'll amend my answer to include info about how to deal with 404 errors

Comment: Hmmm...I know how to handle exception in spring. But my business requirement is little different. I need validate all string in requested URL i.e what ever coming after "http://localhost:8080" and then I need to throw the exception in custom way. So over all I need to catch the request in RequestMapping first.

Comment: If a user make a request let's say "http://localhost:8080/x/y/z" then I need to check whether "x/y/z" exist in db or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need add a [resource handler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html) to your project. This will allow files in your `/resources` folder to pass through. Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources) about it with some example code for reference.

`registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");`

Another option may be to implement an interceptor that catches all URIs before making it to your controller method. This would allow you to add some logic to make sure things exist in the DB prior to actually reaching your controller rather than having a single controller method doing everything. Extending [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) might be something to look into.

Comment: The first suggestion of configuring "resource handler" is already there. But the second suggestion about "interceptor" looks very meaningful to me. I have to try for this one. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe also try adding `registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);` to make sure it takes highest precedence.

Comment: `registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);` did not work for me. This is useful I guess when you have multiple resources to handle.