# Spring Boot Security configure Cache for AngularJS frontend

Tags: angularjs, caching, spring-boot

I use **AngularJS** at *frontend* and **Spring Boot and Security** in *Backend*.
The *frontend* structure looks like this:

[image: frontend]

and in *Spring* I have this classes:

[image: backend]

The class *MvcConfigurer* currently looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    }
}
```

My question now is:

*What do I have to write into the **addResourceHandlers** method in order to enable caching at Browser frontend.*

Answer (score 0):

In **addResourceHandlers** you should register the application resources, stored in the WAR file, that needs to be served.

Here is an example of a JavaScript files resolver:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("../webapp/js/");
}
```

Also, you can append **.setCachePeriod(** time_in_seconds **)** so the browser will cache this resolvers in order to optimize request handling.

Please read more details in [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) by Baeldung. I think you'll find it quite useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tome for your answer, it was really helpful. I would have one more question, In my Spring Boot final jar I have a lib folder with a lot of jars, one jar is called e.g. A.jar where the class **MvcConfigurer** is in it and the other jar is called B.jar where the frontend files are in it. My question now would be how to set the path for **registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("../webapp/js/");** Is ist possible also to specify the the jar name in the path?

Comment: Regarding your additional question, here is a similar existing Stack Overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources.

Comment: I would also recommend you to watch some of the courses by Jeva Brains https://javabrains.io. He is quite good in explaining the basics of setting up an application with Java/Spring and also using correctly the other tools like Maven, Hibernate, etc.