# Spring Boot does not load Bootstrap in jsp file

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Today i have a problem with Bootstrap in my Spring Boot app.

Spefically, when i start the app and open the browser, i can see my page but with "classic" html; that is, i don't see the page formatted with the css of Bootstrap but with normal html5 (so, Bootstrap is nota loaded).

What i have done?

First, i've download Boostrap framework; then i try to put the 3 folder css, js and fonts under both this path:

```
src/main/webapp          (first)
src/main/resource/static (then)
```

In the second case, i tried also to move from `/static` folder into resource, that is `src/main/resource`

When i've put this 3 folder in `resource` and `resource/static`, i tried 2 configuration:

1. add in `application.properties`  file this line of code: `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/`
2. Use a `MvcConfiguration` class that extends the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class and override the method `addResourceHandlers` this way:

   `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
   {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                   .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }`

Of course, done this, in my jsp file (located under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`) i'v put the 2 line of code to tell the page where take the css and js file:

```
<link href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and of course, these line change from `/resource/static/` with `/webapp` when i try to put under `src/main/webapp` the 3 Bootstrap folder. But, after this, i cannot see Bootstrap loaded. What i wrong?

Update: solved. The problem was based on a setting in my applications.properties:

server.port=8080
server.contextPath=/polaris

that is, the change of the context path. A usefull tread on this site is this: [Spring 4 - addResourceHandlers not resolving the static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources)

Comment: have you tried to clear your cache / different browsers between attempts?

Comment: Yes, both them; clear the cache was the first thing I thinked.

Comment: Did you try checking with inspect element of browser that your `bootstrap-css` is loading as part of resources?

Comment: Dont use jsp's anymore, they are outdated relicts of Java technology ;)

Comment: Stimpson, you are right but my boss want that i use them. Sajjad, no i've not try; and i admit my ignorance. What i must find inspecting the page?
And using firefox, wich option i must choose after right click of mouse? Page source? Page analisys? Page Information?

Comment: Try to inspect your developer console in browser. Cntrl + Shift + K in firefox, Cntrl +Shft + I in Chrome.  You can see console, network tabs to find out where your browser is loading there resources from. If its a 404 error there then the file may not be there on server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Praneeth. Tomorrow i will try.

Answer (score 0):

Using in JSP by link href and give path like static/css/somename.css

Do 4 Step:
  1.maven-Clean 
  2.update project
  3.maven install
  4.Run As Spring Boot App

Hope it will help.
[The Path Of Any CSS Should be Like This in Spring Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yItX4.jpg)

Comment: Ok, i tried both suggestion of Rajesh and Praaneth and the problem persist but now i know why: as Praanet suppose, i have a 404 error and it's impossible to load file. So, i can continue from this. Tank you very much, both you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following link for spring boot with boostrap template on web application. [example_link](https://github.com/idthusitha/spring-boot-web-application). You have to change following property values on application.properties file inside the above application for jsp page load. Make sure inside webapp folder having correct name.

- spring.mvc.view.prefix=/html/
- spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html