# Webjars-locator doesn't work with XML based Spring MVC 4.2.x configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classpath, webjars

I have a `Spring MVC 4.2.x` project. I am configuring it via `XML` based configuration file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In the `context.xml` file I have configured resources and `annotation-driven` mode:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Everything works fine except the one thing: `webjars-locator` - **Webjars locator doesn't work at all**.

---

I've started look into the Spring MVC sources to understand what's going wrong, and found, that `webjars-locator` works through `WebJarsResourceResolver` class, which's object is added in the `ResourceChainRegistration.getResourceResolvers()` class method.

The full sequence looks like:

`WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping()` >> `ResourceHandlerRegistration.getHandlerMapping()` >> `ResourceHandlerRegistration.getRequestHandler()` >>
`ResourceChainRegistration.getResourceResolvers()`, where it is added as:

```
if (isWebJarsAssetLocatorPresent) {
    result.add(new WebJarsResourceResolver());
}
```

The problem, is that in case of XML based configuration described above, this sequence is not invoked, neither `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class is used.

Furthermore, if I add

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
}
```

into project, `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` obviously works, but in `ResourceHandlerRegistration.getHandlerMapping()`:

```
protected AbstractHandlerMapping getHandlerMapping() {
    if (registrations.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
...
}
```

`registrations` **is empty!**

---

After all, the only one way how to forcibly make Spring to add `WebJarsResourceResolver` into the resolver chain, is:

1) remove `<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>` from the `context.xml` and

2) add `addResourceHandlers` into `WebConfig`:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true)  // !!! very important
    ;
}
```

---

**My question is**: what am I doing wrong? Why XML bases configuration doesn't cause `WebJarsResourceResolver` to be registered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that the context root path is `/ctx`. With your configuration, a resource path as `/webjars/RESOURCE` is *actually* mapped to `/ctx/webjars/RESOURCE`; in contrary to common expectation that it should be mapped to `/webjars/RESOURCE`.

Based on [Spring 4.2.x documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) and [an example similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources), you need to map `/webjars/**` to the default dispatcher servlet as:

> This allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus overriding the mapping of the container’s default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container’s default Servlet. It configures a DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler with a URL mapping of "/**" and the lowest priority relative to other URL mappings.

which means adding the following should fix the issue:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/">
    <mvc:resource-chain>
        <mvc:resource-cache />
    </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Another note that is [the example petclinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/mvc-core-config.xml#L37) uses `location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"` for webjars which I am not sure is relevant here.

Hope this helps.

---

Added by @Andremoniy:

for `Spring 4` it has slightly different markup:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/">
    <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true"/>
</mvc:resources>
```

Comment: Ha! So the problem is only with `<mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true"/>`, I didn't know this obvious way for specifying it in XML, thank you! This still doesn't answer the question why it isn't described in webjar documentation, but I accept it as it solves the issue in the desired way!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your remaining question ["why it isn't described in webjar documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200423/webjars-locator-doesnt-work-with-xml-based-spring-mvc-4-2-x-configuration#comment75422542_44201118):

It is/was an issue that has been reported on May 3, 2016:

https://github.com/webjars/webjars/issues/1395

As described on this page this issue also mentions that Spring MVC requires the resourceChain() method. I created a PR today to fix the issue:

https://github.com/webjars/webjars/pull/1946

FYI: I tried to get version agnostic url's working the way it was described in the documentation but didn't succeed. Along the way I also found the following issue that mentions that "The resourceChain() method must be called for version-agnostic WebJars":

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25410