# Java Spring MVC Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Java8 with Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE.

I have the following folder structure.

[image: I also have the following config:]

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/", "/www/");
        //registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**").addResourceLocations("/www/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/");
    }
}
```

This allows me to access `html` files in the `webapp` folder.

e.g. `http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/home.html`

**Question**

How do I configure it, so that I can also access html files in the `webapp/www` folder?

e.g. `http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/www/index.html`

returns:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/jbosswildfly-1.0/www/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'rest'

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061237/spring-4-addresourcehandlers-not-resolving-the-static-resources

Comment: Thanks Scary Wombat, I try the following, but no success. `registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/**").addResourceLocations("/webapp/");`

Comment: what happens if you remove the `registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/");` rule.  It seems to be almighty

Comment: Yes, I did remove the almighty `("/")` rule. I tried it with just the one above.

Comment: Thanks Scary Wombat, you pointed me in the right direction. The following worked: `registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");`

Comment: That's cool to hear

Answer (score 0):

You may use The `InternalResourceViewResolver` to set the prefix and suffix part of the path. For example,

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewresolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/www/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zionz, do I just add this method to my existing `MvcConfig` class? Do I need to extend another class?

Comment: The Same class itself.

Comment: `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jbosswildfly-1.0/home.html]` and `[/jbosswildfly-1.0/www/index.html]`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I just found a solution. If I add the following: `registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/")‌​;`